# Sprout Form redirect after submit not working correctly

Tags: form, plugin-sproutforms, redirect

All my forms on sprout form won't use the redirect they get assigned via the Form builder. Whenever a form is succesfully submited it redirects to my homepage instead of my thank-you page.

```
<form class="form__regular" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="contact-form">
    {{ getCsrfInput() }}

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="sprout-forms/entries/save-entry">
    <input type="hidden" name="handle" value="{{ form.handle }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ form.redirectUri }}">
</form>
```

Even if I write the redirect URL manually it keeps redirecting me to the homepage.

The only way I can get the redirect to work is when I let sprout forms render the fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Craft 3, Form redirect values must use the `hash` filter:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="{{ form.redirectUri|hash }}">
```

It's mentioned in passing in the docs [here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/changes-in-craft-3.html#request-params).

Without that `hash` filter, you'll get redirected to the home page as you are experiencing.

Comment: The closing of the tag was just a typo yes, putting the hash filter did the trick.
Should have checked out the Craft 3 changes docs a bit more. Not the first issue I ran into regarding a change made for Sprout Forms in Craft 2 to 3

Comment: Got it. I've removed reference to the typo to as you corrected it in the question too. Just to note it, this isn't a Sprout Forms change, this is a Craft CMS change. In the case forms are not working with Custom HTML, it is a good debugging step to output the form using the `displayForm` tag like you did. If all works via that method, digging into the underlying HTML templates line by line can help start to reveal what might be different.